# How to group array objects into sub objects and count them

Tags: javascript, arrays

I receive an array from an api which looks like this

```js
input = [
  { choices:[
      {"food":"breakfast","preference":"tea"},
      {"food":"lunch","preference":"burger"},
      {"food":"supper","preference":"rice"}
    ]
  },
  { choices:[
      {"food":"breakfast","preference":"coffee"},
      {"food":"lunch","preference":"burger"},
      {"food":"supper","preference":"yam"}
    ]
  },
  { choices:[
      {"food":"breakfast","preference":"tea"},
      {"food":"lunch","preference":"bread"},
      {"food":"supper","preference":"yam"}
    ]
  },
  { choices:[
      {"food":"breakfast","preference":"coffee"},
      {"food":"lunch","preference":"bread"},
      {"food":"supper","preference":"rice"}
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried [Group by the array of objects based on the property and also the count in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635607/group-by-the-array-of-objects-based-on-the-property-and-also-the-count-in-javasc)

I need to group the individual preferences and count them

```js
groupedChoices = [
  [
    { "preference": "tea", "count": 3 },
    { "preference": "coffee", "count": 2 }
  ],
  [
    { "preference": "burger", "count": 3 },
    { "preference": "bread", "count": 2 }
  ],
  [
    { "preference": "rice", "count": 3 },
    { "preference": "yam", "count": 2 }
  ]
]
```

Comment: What's the logic that produces `groupedChoices`?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? What problems do you have with that approach? Where's that approach ([mcve])?

Comment: That is how I want to group them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const input = [
  { choices:[
      {"food":"breakfast","preference":"tea"},
      {"food":"lunch","preference":"burger"},
      {"food":"supper","preference":"rice"}
    ]
  },
  { choices:[
      {"food":"breakfast","preference":"coffee"},
      {"food":"lunch","preference":"burger"},
      {"food":"supper","preference":"yam"}
    ]
  }, 
  {choices: [
      {"food":"breakfast","preference":"tea"},
      {"food":"lunch","preference":"bread"},
      {"food":"supper","preference":"yam"}
    ]
  },
  { choices:[
      {"food":"breakfast","preference":"coffee"},
      {"food":"lunch","preference":"bread"},
      {"food":"supper","preference":"rice"}
    ]
  }
];

const result = input.reduce((acc, { choices }) => {
  choices.forEach(({ food, preference }) => {
    if (!acc[food]) acc[food] = {}
    if (!acc[food][preference]) acc[food][preference] = 1
    else ++acc[food][preference]
  })
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```